# Visual Foxpro 9 - debugging Com server dll from another program

Tags: debugging, dll, visual-foxpro

I have a VFP program and is built as com server dll which is MyClass.dll. 
I am using this dll in VB6 program. Object is created as
Dim var as New MyClass.Test

Where Test is the Class in VFP program
    DEFINE class Test as custom olepublic

I have debugged the code in VFP debugger using VFP command editor and calling the program. At this point, i am able to debug my code and on creating object, debug is hitting the Init function.

I am looking for an option to hit the code when object creation is called from VB6 program( just like we have the option Attach to process in .Net)

Comment: I've found that when debugging VFP COM objects, the best strategy is setting up logging code and logging things to a text file to see what's going on.